# Searching through mutliple values in a list in python

Tags: python, string, list

Suppose I have a list:

```
items = ['matt', 'zen', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cat', 'dog']

if elem in items 
`if 'a' 'b' 'c' found then return 1
```

Whenever elem finds 'a', 'b', 'c' in the list and return a value. Is there a way to define the `list` in such a way? I don't want to have multiple if conditions (if it can be avoided).

Comment: Do you require the ordering to be the same or just that all those elements exist?

Comment: The ordering doesn't matter

Comment: Changed `str` name to `items`, `str` is a [builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if every item is in `items`

```
>>> items = ['matt', 'zen', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cat', 'dog']
>>> {'a', 'b', 'c'}.issubset(items)
True
```

Inside a `for` loop, still taking advantage of the fast (`O(1)` amortized) lookup speeds of `set`s:

```
find = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
for elem in items:
    if elem in find:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Note this adds the restriction of hashable items.

Comment: @jamylak Is there another way to do this, because what I am doing is this: `for elem in items` `return a proper value for elem`

Comment: @JamesHallen  I thought you needed to assure they were all inside `items`, anyway I added a `for` loop check

Comment: Is it possible to use the `in` function for example, maybe combine `'a'+'b'+'c' to 'abc'` and define `subset = ['a']` and `if subset in 'abc' -the do whatever`

Comment: @JamesHallen I'm not following

Comment: So basically, I need to perform some operations if `'at' or 'bat' or 'cat'` found in a `string`. This string could also be defined as either `at or bat or cat`. So if I added the string to 'atbatcat' and `if (at or bat or cat) in atbatcat` then do something

Comment: @JamesHallen `if any(x in string for x in ('at', 'bat', 'cat'))`

Comment: So specific to my work: suppose I have a list called `keys` and I am looking for elemetns within this: `if any(x in keys for x in elem)` elem has individaul string values, but one of the values is like (the example above) `'at bat cat'`, where as one of the elements in the keys at maximum will hold `at or bat or cat`

Comment: @JamesHallen This discussion is now going too long, you'll need to open a new question

Comment: So at some point `x` should take a value of example `at` and will look for this value in `elem`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the subset operator for simple objects such as strings:

```
>>> items = ['matt', 'zen', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cat', 'dog']
>>>> {'a', 'b', 'c'} < set(items)
True
```

Here is a general case :

```
>>> items = ['matt', 'zen', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cat', 'dog']
>>> all(x in items for x in (['a'], 'b', 'c'))
True
```

It still works even though we have an unhashable type in the container.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
for elem in 'abc':
    if elem in str
```